# Navigating to tokens that are not part of the context while parsing java code using antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I am using ANTLR 4.2 to parse a Java source file.

My goal is to locate methods inside a class that have a specific annotation on them.

The problem I am facing is that the [Java.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) grammar does not include `annotation` rule as part of the `methodDeclaration` rule (which makes sense), meaning that it is not directly available to me from the context object when I override `enterMethodDeclaration` of `JavaBaseListener`:

```
@Override
public void enterMethodDeclaration(@NotNull JavaParser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
   // How do I access the annotation on the method in 'ctx'? 
}
```

The only idea I had to so far is to obtain the token stream and try to traverse it backwards from the location of the method declaration context. The problem with that is that it is very cumbersome (The annotation on the method may come before the modifier, after the modifier, that is if a modifier actually exists) and I feel it is missing the point of the listener/visitor approach.

Is there a clean way to get to the annotations on a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to traverse *up* the parse tree, consider going down. You could start in the `classBodyDeclaration` production and check if you can get into a `memberDeclaration` and from there to a `methodDeclaration`. If so, you know you're currently in a method. Then simply iterate over the `modifier` list in the `classBodyDeclaration` to find annotations.

A quick demo:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String input = "@Annotation(\"class\")\n" +
                "class Mu {\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    @Annotation(\"field\")\n" +
                "    int x;\n" +
                "    \n" +
                "    @Annotation(\"method\")\n" +
                "    void withAnnotation(){}\n" +
                "    \n" +
                "    void withoutAnnotation(){}\n" +
                "}";

        JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input));
        JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        //   classBodyDeclaration
        //       :   ...
        //       |   modifier* memberDeclaration
        //       ;
        //
        //   memberDeclaration
        //       :   methodDeclaration
        //       |   ...
        //       ;
        //
        //   methodDeclaration
        //       :   (type|'void') Identifier formalParameters ...
        //       ;
        //
        //   modifier
        //       :   classOrInterfaceModifier
        //       |   ...
        //       ;
        //
        //   classOrInterfaceModifier
        //       :   annotation
        //       |   ...
        //       ;
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new JavaBaseListener(){
            @Override
            public void enterClassBodyDeclaration(@NotNull JavaParser.ClassBodyDeclarationContext ctx) {

                if (!(ctx.memberDeclaration() != null && ctx.memberDeclaration().methodDeclaration() != null)) {
                    // No method declaration.
                    return;
                }

                String methodName = ctx.memberDeclaration().methodDeclaration().Identifier().getText();

                for (JavaParser.ModifierContext mctx : ctx.modifier()) {
                    if (mctx.classOrInterfaceModifier() != null && mctx.classOrInterfaceModifier().annotation() != null) {
                        System.out.println(methodName + " -> " + mctx.classOrInterfaceModifier().annotation().getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, parser.compilationUnit());
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
withAnnotation -> @Annotation("method")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Takes a while to get used to the technique. Thanks.